# Liquibase "Unkown database Hibernate"

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, spring-boot-3, hibernate-6.x

I am using Spring Boot 3 with Spring Data JPA (MySQL8).
I am attempting to generate a liquibase:diff based on my JPA Entities. When I attempt to do so, I have the following error:

> Starting Liquibase at 15:54:24 (version 4.24.0 #14062 built at 2023-09-28 12:18+0000)
> [INFO] Cannot load service: liquibase.database.Database: liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringBeanDatabase Unable to get public no-arg constructor
> [INFO] Cannot load service: liquibase.database.Database: liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringPackageDatabase Unable to get public no-arg constructor
> [INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File ./src/main/resources/liquibase.properties for changeLog parameters
> [INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibasetest
> [WARNING] Unknown database: Hibernate
> [INFO] Performing Diff on database root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibasetest (Default Schema: liquibasetest)
> [WARNING] Potentially ignored key(s) in property file ./src/main/resources/liquibase.properties
>
> changeLogFile'
>
> 'outputChangeLogFile'
>
> [INFO] Error getting default schema
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$QueryCallableStatementCallback.doInCallableStatement (JdbcExecutor.java:579)
> at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute (JdbcExecutor.java:131)
> at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query (JdbcExecutor.java:219)
> at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query (JdbcExecutor.java:230)
> at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject (JdbcExecutor.java:238)
> at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject (JdbcExecutor.java:253)
> at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject (JdbcExecutor.java:248)

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>liquibase.learn</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <liquibase.propertyFile>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\liquibase.properties</liquibase.propertyFile>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.24.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
                    <propertyFile>./src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <!-- <changeLogFile>./src/main/resources/db/changelog.yaml</changeLogFile>
                    <outputChangeLogFile>./src/main/resources/db/changelog.yaml</outputChangeLogFile>
                    <referenceDriver>liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver</referenceDriver>
                    <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:liquibase.learn.server?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
                    <driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver> -->
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                        <version>4.24.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                        <version>4.24.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        <version>6.4.0.CR1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Liquibase.properties

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibasetest
username=root
password=password
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:liquibase.learn.server?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy

changeLogFile=./src/main/resources/db/changelog.yaml
outputChangeLogFile=./src/main/resources/db/changelog.yaml
```

I wanted to create an entity. Make changes to its properties and generate change logs based on those differences.

Comment: I would start by removing the version from the hibernate and liquibase dependencies in your plugin. Those might interfere with the actual supported versions by Spring Boot (and hibernate version that is supported by liquibase).